# getting HTML to send content to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Okay so I'm confused and lost and have no idea of what I am doing, basically here is my code:

**HTML/JavaScript**:

```
<img src="Images/Question1.png" usemap="#mainMap" id="main"/>
 <map name="mainMap" id="mainMap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="82,192,196,242" onclick="incorrectAnswer()" />
 </map
        function incorrectAnswer() {
        document.getElementById("incorrectVid").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("incorrectVid").play();
        document.getElementById("answer_id").value=id;
        document.forms["answer_send"].submit();
    }

<form id="answer_send" name="answer_send" action="answersend.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" id="answer_id" name="answer_id" value="10"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**PHP**:

```
$id=$_POST['answer_id'];
echo $id
```

I have no idea why this is not working any ideas/help?

Comment: You need to give your input a `name` property

Comment: when i just gave it an name attribute when it went to display onto the (answersend.php) the page was blank and the value wasn't there

Comment: You need to close your form element `</form>`.

Comment: i forgot the `</form>` but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

To grab values submitted via GET/POST you need to assign the **name** property to your input fields.  Try the below:

**The HTML and JS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function incorrectAnswer() {
                document.forms["answer_send"].submit();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="none.jpg" alt="placeholder" width="200" height="200" onClick="incorrectAnswer();">
        <form id="answer_send" name="answer_send" action="form.php" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" id="answer_id" name="answer_id" value="10"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**The PHP**

```
<?php
    $id=$_POST['answer_id'];
    echo $id;
?>
```

Note: Your AREA element is not going to work unless you assign it to  something.
Your JavaScript function must be within  tags or you'll receive errors.
The HTML/PHP part of this is working fine... You are experiencing these issues due to the following three lines...

```
document.getElementById("incorrectVid").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("incorrectVid").play();
document.getElementById("answer_id").value=id;
```

Comment: OK, I've updated the code above.  I've tested this and it works fine.  From the code you posted there was no submit option.  All forms must be submitted in someway before it can be grabbed by PHP.  This does not need to be a button, it can be performed on a key event if preferred.

Comment: okay I've just updated my code but when it takes me to the (answersend.php) page it is still blank, I have no idea on why it keeps doing this.

Comment: Silly question: have you got the PHP file hosted on a web server?  If so update your original post with the code you have now and I'll take a look.

Comment: the php file is on a mytestbox server which i use a web address to see my changes/display my outcome, i have re-posted the code i am currently using and hopefully you know where i have gone wrong.

Comment: The `document.getElementById("incorrectVid").style.display="block";` and `document.getElementById("incorrectVid").play();` are for the videos that ive created the reason why the area element is being used and i will paste it in the original code

Answer (score 0):

where is your name attribute ?

Every input must have a name attribute to retrieve it on php
and your html code must look like this:

```
<form id="answer_send" name="answer_send" action="answersend.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" id="answer_id" name="answer_id" value="10"/> </form>
```

Comment: when i just gave it an name attribute when it went to display onto the (answersend.php) the page was blank and the value wasn't there